# Mocking members of immutable classes in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlite, mocking

I have a class which uses a sqlite3 database and want to write a test suite for it. In particular, I want to check that `sqlite3.Cursor.execute` is called with the correct SQL command. However, I have run into trouble with mocking this method since `sqlite3.Cursor` seems to be written in C and thus the class is immutable. This means I can't just patch the execute method, but if I try to patch the whole class, the assert fails, saying that execute was never called.

Below is my best attempt so far, but the assert fails, saying that there was no call. I would appreciate some suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

### myclass.py

```
import sqlite3
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = sqlite3.connect('somedb.db')

    def query(self, sql_squery):
        c = self.db.cursor()
        c.execute(sql_query)
```

### test_myclass.py

```
import unittest
import mock
import myclass

class MyClassTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('myclass.sqlite3.Cursor')
    def test_query(self, mock_sql_cursor):
        mc = myclass.MyClass()
        mc.query('test')
        mock_sql_cursor.execute.assert_called_with('test')
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077247/how-to-mock-sqlite3-connect-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Here goes another approach

You could patch out `myclass.sqlite3` and mock the and then mock the return value of `connect().cursor().execute`.

```
import unittest
from mock import patch
from myclass import MyClass


class MyClassTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_query(self, mock_sql_cursor):
        with patch('uploads.myclass.sqlite3') as mocksql:
            mc = MyClass()
            mc.query('test')
            mock_sql_cursor.connect().cursor().execute.assert_called_with('test')
```

Answer inspired in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536594/how-can-i-mock-sqlite3-cursor)

Comment: Thanks. This worked and seems to be the most concise solution.

Comment: Pay attention to use mock's call instead of `return_value` in test code. Mock `()` calls are reserved to production code and `return_value` is useful in test to have the same value without change the mock state.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite3` is a C extension and you cannot patch C calls. Any way you should not to test `sqlite3` behavior but just your how code the call `sqlite3` module.

What you can do is to patch `sqlite3.connect()` method and check if your code call the API in the correct way:

```
class MyClassTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('sqlite3.connect', autospec=True)
    def test_query(self, mock_connect):
        mock_cursor = mock_connect.return_value.cursor.return_value
        mc = myclass.MyClass()
        mc.query('test')
        mock_cursor.execute.assert_called_with('test')
```

Note:

1. I patch `sqlite3.connect` absolute path and not `myclass....` do the same thing but it is more clear (`sqlite3.connect` and `myclass.sqlite3.connect` are exactly the same reference)
2. I'm using `autospec=True` to avoid strange errors like explained in [Autospeccing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing)
3. Consider to write your own wrapper and mock it in your test: your code will be more testable and less coupled to `sqlite3` module

Comment: Thanks this worked great. Just one question -- why are `sqlite3` and `membership.sqlite3` the same namespace?

I did also consider writing a wrapper class, but it seemed silly to add unnecessary abstraction just to fit my code to the test suite.

Comment: There's no namespace in python. By `import sqlite3` you copy the `sqlite3` module reference in your module and call it `sqlite3`. That means by `myclass.sqlite3.connect` you are pointing the same reference as `sqlite3.connect`

Comment: Everywhere seems to stress the importance of patching something where it is used rather than where the call to patch is. Why is that necessary if all references to a module are the same?

Comment: Because you should patch the reference where you use it but not browse it. Patch the reference where you use is a good rule to make the changes locally but you should know exactly what you are doing. I love to make it explicit by use the absolute path where it is the same.